# Align view bottom to text baseline

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-layout

In ConstraintLayout, is there a way to align the bottom of a View (e.g. ImageView) to the baseline of a TextView? I'm expecting there to be a constraint like `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBaselineOf`, but nothing like that exists.

Note: I've tried `app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`, but it looks like that only works when defined on a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [developer guidelines for `ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html):

> baselines can constrain only to other baselines

and

> ### Baseline alignment
>
> Align the text baseline of a view to the text baseline of another view.

From this, and from my own experimentation, it appears that it is impossible to constrain a generic `View`'s bottom or top to a `TextView`'s baseline.

Answer (score 15):

This might be too late but I hope still helpful for someone who reads the post.

In this specific example, if you want to align an `ImageView` to a `TextView`'s baseline, the default alignment setting for an `ImageView` is applied to the "top", not sure why.. Most likely you want to apply it to the bottom of the `ImageView` which can be achieved by setting `android:baselineAlignBottom="true"` attribute. More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:baselineAlignBottom

So the full code for `ConstraintLayout` will look like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="96dp"
      android:layout_height="96dp"
      android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
      app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textView"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawable1"
      android:contentDescription="@null"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm using an `AppCompatImageView` in my project but I'm pretty sure a regular `ImageView` will work the same way.

The same behavior can also be achieved by a `RelativeLayout` by also adding a `layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView"` to the `ImageView`.

In case this doesn't work for some reason, e.g. you have a custom view or something, you might also consider doing it in runtime.

There is a method in a `TextView`, called `getLastBaselineToBottomHeight`. It returns the distance between the last text baseline and the bottom of this `TextView`. You can apply that value to your `View`'s bottom margin which should give you the same effect. Although the method was only introduced in Android P, you can simply implement it the same way (according to the source code). Just an example that worked for me:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView).getLayoutParams();
params.bottomMargin = textView.getPaddingBottom() + textView.getPaint().getFontMetricsInt().descent;
```

I hope that helps. Good luck!